# reference to microsoft.visualstudio.services.common

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, tfs, iis-8

I am developing a mvc asp.net app to extract some data from a TFS server. After deploying it to an IIS8, when I try to execute the action that connects to the TFS, I get the following message:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   overlord.Utils.TFSServer..ctor(String uri, NetworkCredential credential) +0
   overlord.Utils.TFSServer..ctor() +25
   overlord.Utils.TFSManager.GetServer(String sessionId) +59
   overlord.Controllers.BacklogController.Index() +33
   ...
```

the application works when I debug it on Visual Studio 2013 locally and there's nothing on my code that references microsoft.visualstudio.services.common.

Can you guys help me figure out why the server is trying to load this lib?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least Team Explorer installed on your web server to use the API to yall to TFS.